# Using Finder, how can I view /System/Library?

Tags: finder

Using Finder, how can I view `/System/Library`?

In fact, I'd really like to do the equivalence of a recursive `grep` for file names from the root directory using Finder. How can I move around the entire file system with Finder?

Comment: in terminal: open /any/path/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press **⇧⌘G** (Shift-Command-G) to bring up **Go to Folder** and type in the path, then click **Go** *as shown in the image below*.  Or if using the mouse or trackpad, click: **Finder** > **Go** > **Go to Folder**

[image: Go to Folder]

You can also change Finder Preferences to show Hard disks on the Desktop under General and or in Devices under Sidebar, thus being able to open the Macintosh HD from the *root* of the partition without having to use Go to Folder.

Comment: You can also manually tools>go to folder, or whatever it is!